# Updating student record in binary file, deletes previous data aswell

Tags: c++, oop, file-io

I am trying to update student record by searching his roll no and then moving to that position using tellg() and seekp(). But whenever I try to overwrite, it deletes previous record.

```
int pos=0; 
Student obj;   
ifstream readfile("New.dat",ios::binary);

cout<<"Enter Roll # of student";       
cin>>a;

while(!readfile.eof())
{
    readfile.read((char *) &obj, sizeof(obj));

    if(obj.getRoll()==a)
    {
        if(!readfile.eof())
        {
            pos=readfile.tellg();  
            obj.show();
            cout<<"PLease Enter New Details of Student \n";
            obj.get();
            readfile.close();                
            ofstream file("New.dat",ios::binary);
            file.seekp(pos);
            file.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));  
            cout<<"Student Record Has Been Updated \n";
            countt=1;
        }
    }
}

file.close();
```

Comment: We might be able to help you better if you provide a reproducible example. One way in which you might do that with binary data is to post a simple program that will generate the initial binary data for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a record of the position in the file **before** you read the object, so you can then get back to the same position to write the object out again.

Move your `pos=readfile.tellg();` line to before the `readfile.read` line.

Comment: i have tried this way but the problem is still there,it deletes all previous records except record that was updated.